# How to run tests from the command line ? (IntelliJ Idea + Java +TestNG)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm kind of new to Java and IntelliJ Environments

I managed to create a simple TestNG test inside IntelliJ (Only contains one assertion) and run it.

What are the ordered steps that I need to do in order to be able to run from the command line

I tried different approaches and nothing worked so far

Eventually I would like to run selenium but by now I'm OK with only running that simple assertion...

Comment: Well, you need a test runner. How about using maven with the surefire plugin?

Comment: What does it mean that I need a test runner ?

I would like to run the testng.xml 

I'm used to C# where I can compile DLLs of an NUnit project and then run them witn Nunit console, I'm trying to get a similar behaviour...

Thanks !!!

Comment: When I mean running from command line I mean from Windows cmd, powershell, bat file, something like that ...

Comment: Hi,

Finally I managed to run tests from the command line, still I'm not sure if is the right way.

What I did at the end is

1) Create a new folder and put there the JAR of my test project and also the JARs of TestNG (I take them from C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.6\plugins\testng)

2) Run like this

java -cp "PathToFolderCreatedOnStep1" org.testng.TestNG "PathToXMLFile"

Answer (score 0):

From the official docs at http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng

> Assuming that you have TestNG in your class path, the simplest way to invoke TestNG is as follows:

```
java org.testng.TestNG testng1.xml
```

Comment: How can I verify if I have TestNG on my class path ?

What should I have on my MANIFEST.MF ? (Maybe that is being problematic ?)

Comment: Sorry, but I answered to your specific question. This is another question and you should either google it or post a new question on SO.